# New to kotlin - textview editing is failing

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently in a android app development course and am brand new to kotlin. Right now I'm working on building a basic pizza ordering application that once the user makes selections and hits "submit" a textview is edited to show the total price... Except that I cant get the textview to display anything. What am i missing here because i followed the book step-by-step (but it seems to be fairly old) thank you so much!

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

fun onPlaceOrderButtonClicked(view: View) {
    var pizzaSizePrice=0.0
    var toppingsTotal = 0.0
    when {
        radioGroup.smallpizza.isChecked -> pizzaSizePrice=5.0
        radioGroup.mediumpizza.isChecked -> pizzaSizePrice=7.0
        radioGroup.largepizza.isChecked -> pizzaSizePrice=9.0
        }
    if (OnionsCheckBox.isChecked){toppingsTotal+=1}
    if (OlivesCheckBox.isChecked){toppingsTotal+=2}
    if (TomatoesCheckBox.isChecked){toppingsTotal+=3}
Totalprice.text=("Total order price= $" + (pizzaSizePrice+toppingsTotal))
}



}
```

Comment: where is the button "submit"  can you include the full code of this activity  ?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like your code calls `onPlaceOrderButtonClicked`, try adding this:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       
        // Calls your function when button is clicked
        orderButton.setOnClickListener {
            onPlaceOrderButtonClicked()
        }
    }
```

This will direct clicks from the button with id `orderButton` to `onPlaceOrderButtonClicked()`. Also, remove `view: View` from that function, it's not being used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you aren't calling the `onPlaceOrderButtonClicked()`, there a number of ways to handle this. I'm my guess is your book is using the XML approach because the `onPlacedORderButtonClicked()` has a view argument. Try including an onClick in the button XML.

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_orderpizza"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PLUS"
            android:onClick="onPlaceOrderButtonClicked" />
```